# Is there a way to delete an object in list by value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the 'list.remove' function does not compare objects by value

suppose the code is:

```
class item:
def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.feild1 = a
    self.field2 = b

a = item(1,4)
b = item(1,4)
l = [a]
l.remove(b) # doesn't remove l[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't provide a `__eq__` implementation, your class inherits the method from `object`.  `object.__eq__` doesn't compare the values of attribute, it just checks to see that `id(a) == id(b)`. You need to write your own `__eq__`:

```
class item:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.field1 = a
        self.field2 = b
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, item):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.field1 == other.field1 and self.field2 == other.field2

a = item(1,4)
b = item(1,4)
l = [a]
l.remove(b)

print(l)
# []
```